# Should I exclude an individual being evaluated from group average?

Tags: mean

I am working on some statistics of work related performances. Now at first I did my code to calculate the performance of a single individual and compared it to the average of a group in which the individual was included.

This got me thinking. Should I, or should I not include this individual in the group result average?

If I include the individual then the person is not only being compared to the group average but also to him- or herself and depending on the size of the group this might influence more or less.

On the other hand, if I remove the individual from the group, the group looses it's integrity and does not model reality.

Is there a general position on this? What questions do these two approaches answer?

If anyone could point me in a direction I could read more I would be grateful.

Comment: It's often done; whether it's a good idea depends on the research question, as @Dirk Horsten points out in his answer. Note that (missing values aside) the average of others is just (total - this value) / (count - 1) so (a point often missed in my experience) no loop should be needed to calculate these quantities.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand your formula to loop connection. You say just, implicating that the outcome is not affected much. But if the selected individual is an outlier and the group is small the outcome is severely affected. Math aside I am more interested in the loop part. Are you referring to programming? I do not frequent this forum usually and am not statistician so I am not familiar with the lingo.

Comment: When I say "just" I mean only that it's a trivial calculation; you are right that an outlier makes a big difference. Worked example: values  1, 2, 3; so total 6 and count 3. The means of others are a single vectorised calculation [(6 6 6) $-$ (1 2 3)] / (3 $-$ 1).  I've seen people write loops to do that. I am not a statistician either: as a geographer I probably qualify as a lower life-form.

Answer (score 2):

The answer depends on the question, including its context.

### Replace an employee or not?

Suppose you have 10 employees, hired through the same process. One of them is performing worse and you consider replacing him.

Then you should compare him with the expected performance of a new hire, and to estimate that, you must include **all** people you hired in the past.

### Stick with the new recruiter?

Suppose you hired 9 employees yourself and one via a recruiter. Now you need one employee more. Will you go through the recruiter or not?

Now you must compare the individual with the **other** employees.

Comment: Thank you for the input. It seems it is not as simple as I would have hoped. I will have to put some thought into this and weigh the options.